# segmentation fault in pandas after iopro (adapter for CSV)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, segmentation-fault, anaconda

I am not sure I understand what's going on. My simple code below run OK on an up-to-date Anaconda environment on a Windows server three weeks ago (Python 2.7.5 64-bit, pandas, IOPro). Now I fixed a bug and reran the script but now it crashes, but only on the third (though larger) file in the loop, after the adapter being set up OK. Windows simply said that I can close the program or look for a solution online and close the program. This happened in a console from the command prompt, or iPython, or Spyder.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import iopro
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

all_treatments  = DataFrame()
filelist = ['oppenvard2011','oppenvard2012','oppenvard20012005','oppenvard20062010','slutenvard1997','slutenvard2011','slutenvard2012','slutenvard19982004','slutenvard20052010']

tobacco = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'C30') and (x<'C40')) or ((x >= 'F17') and (x<'F18')))  for x in lst)

for file in filelist:
    filename = '~/Desktop/treatments/' + file +'.txt'
    adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename,parser='csv',field_names=True,output='dataframe',delimiter='\t')
    treatments = adapter[['LopNr','AR','DIAGNOS']][:]
    diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ')
    ### CRASH HAPPENS HERE ON THIRD ITERATION, THE LINE ABOVE DOES NOT COMPLETE
    del treatments['DIAGNOS']
    treatments['tobacco'] = diagnoses.map(tobacco)
    all_treatments = all_treatments.append(treatments)
```

Now I tried on my mac too, with an up-to-date miniconda with the relevant packages, and the mac says I run into a segmentation fault. Can I do anything about this? Is this common, or maybe I should downgrade to earlier versions? Which ones? Just try a modified (but still fast) version of the code?

To be clear: I could imagine running out of RAM on my mac (for all intents and purposes) but not on the server.

In any case, here is the mac error message. Thanks!

```
Process:         python2.7 [93474] Path:
/Users/USER/*/python2.7 Identifier:      python2.7 Version:        
??? Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  bash [93426]
Responsible:     Terminal [93418] User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-05-25 01:59:06.976 +0200 OS Version:      Mac OS
X 10.9.3 (13D65) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID: 
C43838E1-4AB0-4D6B-F8CE-448D9B7D9AD4

Sleep/Wake UUID: 1E7EAACA-A5A4-4DD2-8B38-DF1E0A53E1AB

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xffffffffffccc1c6

VM Regions Near 0xffffffffffccc1c6:
--> shared memory          00007ffffff5a000-00007ffffff5b000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM  


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0  
libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000611b8 PyObject_Malloc + 88
1   libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100069656
PyString_FromStringAndSize + 150 2   libpython2.7.dylib           
  0x000000010006af49 string_split + 1065 3   libpython2.7.dylib        
  0x00000001000c8f49 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24313 4   libpython2.7.dylib 
  0x00000001000cad35 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 5   libpython2.7.dylib   
  0x00000001000407d2 function_call + 178 6   libpython2.7.dylib        
  0x000000010000d382 PyObject_Call + 98 7   lib.so                     
  0x0000000106d89cb9 __pyx_pw_6pandas_3lib_159map_infer_mask + 1769 8  
libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000c8f49 PyEval_EvalFrameEx +
24313 9   libpython2.7.dylib              0x00000001000cad35
PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 10  libpython2.7.dylib           
  0x00000001000c8e56 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24070 11  libpython2.7.dylib 
  0x00000001000cad35 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 12  libpython2.7.dylib   
  0x00000001000c8e56 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24070 13  libpython2.7.dylib 
  0x00000001000cad35 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 14  libpython2.7.dylib   
  0x00000001000c8e56 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24070 15  libpython2.7.dylib 
  0x00000001000cad35 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 16  libpython2.7.dylib   
  0x00000001000c8e56 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24070 17  libpython2.7.dylib 
  0x00000001000cad35 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733 18  libpython2.7.dylib   
  0x00000001000cb036 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 19  libpython2.7.dylib       
  0x00000001000ef62e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174 20  libpython2.7.dylib    
  0x00000001000f0446 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 790 21 
libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010010834b Py_Main + 3003 22 
python                            0x0000000100000f54 start + 52

Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87543716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8d747c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   interpreter.so       
  0x0000000107254c5f th_worker(void*) + 191 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib
  0x00007fff8d745899 _pthread_body + 138 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib   
  0x00007fff8d74572a _pthread_start + 137 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib  
  0x00007fff8d749fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87543716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8d747c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   interpreter.so       
  0x0000000107254c5f th_worker(void*) + 191 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib
  0x00007fff8d745899 _pthread_body + 138 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib   
  0x00007fff8d74572a _pthread_start + 137 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib  
  0x00007fff8d749fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87543716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8d747c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   interpreter.so       
  0x0000000107254c5f th_worker(void*) + 191 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib
  0x00007fff8d745899 _pthread_body + 138 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib   
  0x00007fff8d74572a _pthread_start + 137 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib  
  0x00007fff8d749fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87543716
__psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff8d747c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727 2   interpreter.so       
  0x0000000107254c5f th_worker(void*) + 191 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib
  0x00007fff8d745899 _pthread_body + 138 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib   
  0x00007fff8d74572a _pthread_start + 137 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib  
  0x00007fff8d749fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
0x0000000000000008  rbx: 0x0000000000000028  rcx: 0x0000000100278000 
rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000028  rsi:
0xffffffffffccc1c6  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfdea0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfde70  
r8: 0x0000000000000005   r9: 0x0000000175700000  r10:
0x000000010012e9f8  r11: 0x0000000080a1f211   r12: 0x0000000000000004 
r13: 0x0000000000000001  r14: 0x0000000000000008  r15:
0x000000010017cf80   rip: 0x00000001000611b8  rfl: 0x0000000000010207 
cr2: 0xffffffffffccc1c6    Logical CPU:     1 Error Code:     
0x00000004 Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000ff7 +python (???) <1648C061-F47B-8D44-D782-4BB4352E9005> /Users/USER/*/python
       0x100003000 -        0x100167ff3 +libpython2.7.dylib (2.7) <D39C3E1B-6B7F-D509-0FB4-7A5C05FE73A7>
/Users/USER/*/libpython2.7.dylib
       0x1002f4000 -        0x1002f9fff +_struct.so (???) <8FCF2DE6-EE67-93EF-7C9A-4D09F587118C> /Users/USER/*/_struct.so
       0x1004f1000 -        0x1004f5fef +math.so (???) <9A88084C-722D-B5F3-CEBE-B91504BE5B72> /Users/USER/*/math.so
       0x1004fc000 -        0x1004fdff7 +_functools.so (???) <C9BFC859-8D1F-8C2D-94F9-F8582BFD3568> /Users/USER/*/_functools.so
       0x102800000 -        0x1028eafe3 +TextAdapter.so (???) <4CE4C433-483A-EA3A-B83D-B9033579FEAF> /Users/USER/*/TextAdapter.so
       0x102942000 -        0x10295bff6 +libz.1.2.7.dylib (1.2.7) <D8E5E609-0A99-EBDF-A7B9-84DBD279D8F5> /Users/USER/*/libz.1.2.7.dylib
       0x10295f000 -        0x102976ffb +_ctypes.so (???) <30252B35-DE4E-F4A6-BF93-EE7C4B7310B5> /Users/USER/*/_ctypes.so
       0x102987000 -        0x102a97ff7 +multiarray.so (???) <FF255656-C1A3-3661-A052-77866A33030A> /Users/USER/*/multiarray.so
       0x102b3e000 -        0x102b4cff7 +datetime.so (???) <CD6F5D2B-16BB-42A5-44FE-F938AEA680A4> /Users/USER/*/datetime.so
       0x102b98000 -        0x102be7ff7 +umath.so (???) <7137FA28-505E-3484-AFE1-AE7754E6B822> /Users/USER/*/umath.so
       0x102c13000 -        0x102c17ff7 +_collections.so (???) <92FF441A-B09D-751A-B199-02F753738C86> /Users/USER/*/_collections.so
       0x102c1d000 -        0x102c21fff +operator.so (???) <AA4D2A59-782B-20FE-E4A4-C8DD22B37B24> /Users/USER/*/operator.so
       0x102c28000 -        0x102c2fff7 +itertools.so (???) <BCD34E3E-5DD1-D430-3221-15DAB51E98C7> /Users/USER/*/itertools.so
       0x102c3a000 -        0x102c3bfff +_heapq.so (???) <A4CD862B-AA14-D1D3-8E25-25EE02718477> /Users/USER/*/_heapq.so
       0x102c3f000 -        0x102c4fff7 +cPickle.so (???) <CC86FB00-FB1A-D6B0-E022-278745E15434> /Users/USER/*/cPickle.so
       0x102c97000 -        0x102c99ff7 +cStringIO.so (???) <C5DBC726-2E0A-1AD9-E8C1-DAE439ADC15E> /Users/USER/*/cStringIO.so
       0x102c9e000 -        0x102ca1fff +_dotblas.so (???) <4D38AC11-DFCB-3BF3-91A6-70CB10480D15> /Users/USER/*/_dotblas.so
       0x102ca5000 -        0x1034bffff +libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib (0) <5788E2BB-1AE0-36E2-B511-016F9F045647>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
       0x103586000 -        0x10440afff +libmkl_intel_thread.dylib (0) <F1F7D1CC-9AB9-32F1-8A4C-49B32AE1C5C1>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib
       0x104813000 -        0x105b6dfe7 +libmkl_core.dylib (0) <DDDCB14C-5D3E-304F-8FFB-B2CF61331563> /Users/USER/*/libmkl_core.dylib
       0x105d5e000 -        0x105e30fcf +libiomp5.dylib (5) <0F6E6453-A6B5-378F-B6DE-3F73ECCE2437> /Users/USER/*/libiomp5.dylib
       0x105f42000 -        0x105f63ff7 +scalarmath.so (???) <3CDCA64B-E5E1-3FEA-B3E4-FCF93E06CEB0> /Users/USER/*/scalarmath.so
       0x105ff5000 -        0x105ff7fff +time.so (???) <445451E7-4720-C411-3561-FDE718248557> /Users/USER/*/time.so
       0x105ffd000 -        0x106001ff7 +_compiled_base.so (???) <96558EEB-3E9A-3A19-A299-7984A2C8DD63> /Users/USER/*/_compiled_base.so
       0x106045000 -        0x10604bfff +lapack_lite.so (???) <B79976BD-200D-368E-9964-0397B9156F40> /Users/USER/*/lapack_lite.so
       0x1060cf000 -        0x1060d5ff7 +_json.so (???) <5D911C91-5F3F-CC9E-B717-3AFDEAFCF0B4> /Users/USER/*/_json.so
       0x1060da000 -        0x1060dcff7 +binascii.so (???) <5BCFFE6B-0FD9-EAAE-6A03-855E6F8FF581> /Users/USER/*/binascii.so
       0x1060e0000 -        0x1060e1ff7 +_hashlib.so (???) <B1272713-0B2B-2A07-ACF3-9625B963E486> /Users/USER/*/_hashlib.so
       0x1060e5000 -        0x1060e6ff7 +_random.so (???) <AE961035-5BB2-59AA-C889-F8540AA1BF9F> /Users/USER/*/_random.so
       0x1060e9000 -        0x1060eafff +fcntl.so (???) <2C925806-DA60-1048-905F-502DBC905C1D> /Users/USER/*/fcntl.so
       0x1060ed000 -        0x1060edff7 +grp.so (???) <275CA9F9-8F09-7D67-1E8A-91000FCB0EB9> /Users/USER/*/grp.so
       0x1060f0000 -        0x1060f0fff +future_builtins.so (???) <7484FE65-53E6-6B7D-7A51-FC743EAE9202>
/Users/USER/*/future_builtins.so
       0x1060f3000 -        0x1060fbff7 +fftpack_lite.so (???) <D41862DE-50E0-3C7E-9D88-EB8A546A1B69> /Users/USER/*/fftpack_lite.so
       0x106200000 -        0x106253fef +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (1) <6CE01697-9420-F979-5E6E-BD7F97D4ECD3>
/Users/USER/*/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x106270000 -        0x1063d3fdf +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (1) <2E15324A-5E0E-96B2-50B1-CACA77C0CD63>
/Users/USER/*/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x106442000 -        0x106458ff7 +_io.so (???) <5EAEB331-7D89-8479-473C-3A88738E5B01> /Users/USER/*/_io.so
       0x10646f000 -        0x10647eff7 +_umath_linalg.so (???) <203D3CE7-4942-38DE-AA36-8E53D75BAC4C> /Users/USER/*/_umath_linalg.so
       0x10648a000 -        0x10648dfff +strop.so (???) <FC4626C0-4ED8-931B-2B73-00B4E79066A7> /Users/USER/*/strop.so
       0x106592000 -        0x1065c9ff7 +mtrand.so (???) <E9A06D51-D10B-36EA-B348-82D48FE625D8> /Users/USER/*/mtrand.so
       0x106618000 -        0x10661bfff +zlib.so (???) <4E783B3D-612F-8C15-E4D3-5AA5A9A1DA63> /Users/USER/*/zlib.so
       0x106620000 -        0x106623fff +_csv.so (???) <8F624440-CE65-BDE2-A35A-BE9E830CB24B> /Users/USER/*/_csv.so
       0x106629000 -        0x106632fff +_socket.so (???) <E335B158-531F-D78F-0C11-6B60C475AC86> /Users/USER/*/_socket.so
       0x10663e000 -        0x106642fff +_ssl.so (???) <1630185C-425B-1DBE-5115-DCC255429027> /Users/USER/*/_ssl.so
       0x106647000 -        0x106647ff7 +_scproxy.so (???) <E56E51D3-D0AD-470F-E500-F832851ADFF2> /Users/USER/*/_scproxy.so
       0x10668a000 -        0x1066c9ff7 +hashtable.so (???) <C6E48D6E-562B-493F-4981-41D47940F392> /Users/USER/*/hashtable.so
       0x1066de000 -        0x1067c6fef +tslib.so (???) <D7FC451B-8B7B-F2F8-BF81-B70B0EC1379C> /Users/USER/*/tslib.so
       0x106810000 -        0x106816ff7 +array.so (???) <50A872B5-51AB-23C6-CFD5-1CD9487EF1C3> /Users/USER/*/array.so
       0x10685d000 -        0x10685ffff +_locale.so (???) <E6FDC3F0-A78D-8309-DFA8-8C0F7909E525> /Users/USER/*/_locale.so
       0x106be2000 -        0x106bf0ff7 +parser.so (???) <C0A39677-EE22-D468-7297-F52AB5DF1750> /Users/USER/*/parser.so
       0x106bf6000 -        0x106bf6ff7 +_bisect.so (???) <B882D1CC-1BBC-D51D-A1B8-5099C54B9327> /Users/USER/*/_bisect.so
       0x106bfb000 -        0x106bfbff7 +_dynfunc.so (???) <70BD67DF-3036-07AA-99BF-D41ECC2B2444> /Users/USER/*/_dynfunc.so
       0x106d00000 -        0x106d33fe7 +pyexpat.so (???) <77C3042F-3CB9-DD83-C1FE-66CA49A6B951> /Users/USER/*/pyexpat.so
       0x106d45000 -        0x106dfeff7 +lib.so (???) <B0158CD4-3789-65C7-DB8F-F97205C7B866> /Users/USER/*/lib.so
       0x106e36000 -        0x107048ff7 +algos.so (???) <C03F4D81-4AEE-94AD-5CA1-A633E7A467E8> /Users/USER/*/algos.so
       0x1070a3000 -        0x1070d1fef +index.so (???) <03BBC483-BA6B-4F1F-E0A4-10BCFA1639ED> /Users/USER/*/index.so
       0x1070e5000 -        0x107122ff7 +_sparse.so (???) <47BFD27F-884B-F65C-DC84-C73BFD63AC9E> /Users/USER/*/_sparse.so
       0x107135000 -        0x107138fff +select.so (???) <0986B6CA-E9D7-063F-E9E3-4A80F2FE08E2> /Users/USER/*/select.so
       0x10723e000 -        0x10725bfff +interpreter.so (???) <F4A1292F-923A-3742-A87D-D0B4B3F83F47> /Users/USER/*/interpreter.so
       0x107287000 -        0x107965ff7 +libmkl_intel_ilp64.dylib (0) <B27FF1E3-D6AD-3533-B3B1-04E4DCDDD51C>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_intel_ilp64.dylib
       0x107a2a000 -        0x10930bfff +libmkl_mc.dylib (0) <5FC558A6-1C8F-3CAC-AFD6-0E4D41741DB2> /Users/USER/*/libmkl_mc.dylib
       0x1093d1000 -        0x10aefdfef +libmkl_mc3.dylib (0) <0BDA9A67-34EC-3B2E-A7C9-C80A3A364557> /Users/USER/*/libmkl_mc3.dylib
       0x10b037000 -        0x10b7c3fcf +libmkl_vml_mc.dylib (0) <4EAC6CF1-D099-3C57-8FE5-AF89179F9F4C>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_vml_mc.dylib
       0x10b864000 -        0x10bff0fd7 +libmkl_vml_mc2.dylib (0) <5AC3D16B-7F49-368A-B92A-8569580CB9E1>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_vml_mc2.dylib
       0x10c08b000 -        0x10c861fe7 +libmkl_vml_mc3.dylib (0) <BE747346-D47B-3DC0-903E-6158D1474EF0>
/Users/USER/*/libmkl_vml_mc3.dylib
       0x10c8f5000 -        0x10d0c6ff7 +libmkl_rt.dylib (0) <446138E8-8686-3853-9469-5FF2ED63936F> /Users/USER/*/libmkl_rt.dylib
       0x10d4d2000 -        0x10d4e3fef +json.so (???) <FBDD469D-6286-6C36-257D-9AC383419BFE> /Users/USER/*/json.so
       0x10d4ec000 -        0x10d4eeff7 +_typeconv.so (???) <3F51455F-8B54-A232-5B92-A2A930A9412D> /Users/USER/*/_typeconv.so
       0x10d4f2000 -        0x10d4f4ff7 +_capsule.so (???) <9E794CC3-3A48-CAB2-1504-21D512B78CF4> /Users/USER/*/_capsule.so
       0x10d4f9000 -        0x10d4f9fff +_numpyadapt.so (???) <717AD72A-B005-E6ED-B1BD-22A835F6B292> /Users/USER/*/_numpyadapt.so
       0x10d4fc000 -        0x10d4fdff7 +_internal.so (???) <F3A3F5AB-F079-A0A7-01DC-5E0D865FCBA9> /Users/USER/*/_internal.so
       0x10d700000 -        0x10d753fff +parser.so (???) <1C1901A6-BB75-0AB6-7336-D14BF1C5308F> /Users/USER/*/parser.so
       0x10d833000 -        0x10d849fff +msgpack.so (???) <754B195F-8D16-673C-73A4-788441BA8CAD> /Users/USER/*/msgpack.so
       0x10d8dc000 -        0x10d8dffff +_helperlib.so (???) <3EA24D67-AAE2-AA97-A116-CE4EA92EC98B> /Users/USER/*/_helperlib.so
       0x10d8e6000 -        0x10d8e9fff +_dispatcher.so (???) <C6A4C187-99FC-9A16-521D-830CCF6CAB9A> /Users/USER/*/_dispatcher.so
       0x10d8ee000 -        0x10d8f0fff +_npymath_exports.so (???) <F1D71EF9-1860-CAF6-1F89-D3D2F30CDC0B>
/Users/USER/*/_npymath_exports.so
       0x10da00000 -        0x10da88ff7 +_api.so (???) <3E8BE3D5-C1FF-2035-2AF7-625A1B540E4D> /Users/USER/*/_api.so
       0x10db19000 -        0x10f3cdf9f +libLLVM-3.3.dylib (0) <5D138995-D3DD-6959-1006-DDB5720FCBF8> /Users/USER/*/libLLVM-3.3.dylib
       0x1106cc000 -        0x1106ebfef +MongoAdapter.so (???) <C1FD4E1C-57C9-3C80-EC52-B79CFBF461CA> /Users/USER/*/MongoAdapter.so
    0x7fff6ad6a000 -     0x7fff6ad9d817  dyld (239.4) <042C4CED-6FB2-3B1C-948B-CAF2EE3B9F7A> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff804fc000 -     0x7fff8054efff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff81df2000 -     0x7fff81df9fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141>
/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8242d000 -     0x7fff82456ff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff82476000 -     0x7fff8247dff3  libcopyfile.dylib (103) <5A881779-D0D6-3029-B371-E3021C2DDA5E>
/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff828fe000 -     0x7fff82908fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D>
/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff82915000 -     0x7fff82963fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7>
/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff832e3000 -     0x7fff832ecff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8331a000 -     0x7fff8331bff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11) <B46E4040-A8C6-3EBC-91F8-F1CB01106614>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff83dd7000 -     0x7fff83e25ff9  libstdc++.6.dylib (60) <0241E6A4-1368-33BE-950B-D0A175C41F54> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8413a000 -     0x7fff8417cff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8417d000 -     0x7fff84197fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.92.1) <C4E4A18D-3C3B-3C9C-8709-A4270D998DE7>
/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff848af000 -     0x7fff848b0ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF>
/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff848bc000 -     0x7fff848c1fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8540e000 -     0x7fff8541fff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8570f000 -     0x7fff85736ffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff85889000 -     0x7fff85889ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8588a000 -     0x7fff85892fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.90.2) <A0B7CF19-D9F2-33D4-8107-A62184C9066E>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8651d000 -     0x7fff86523ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff86808000 -     0x7fff869c0ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (511.32) <A7CE7DAD-D3AD-36A2-BE4F-25C5F21FADBB> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff869c1000 -     0x7fff869c5ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff86aa1000 -     0x7fff86aa2fff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff86c47000 -     0x7fff86c4eff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.90.1) <38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8752e000 -     0x7fff8754aff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.100.13) <498AEBD7-4194-3CF2-AA16-D5D03FFBD8C0>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8754b000 -     0x7fff8754dff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.15) <4998CB6A-9D54-390A-9F57-5D1AC53C135C>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff875f1000 -     0x7fff875f2ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100)
<4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E>
/usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff87c2c000 -     0x7fff87c2dff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <E303F2F8-A8CF-3DF3-84B3-F2D0EE41CCF6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff87c2e000 -     0x7fff87c3efff  libbsm.0.dylib (33) <2CAC00A2-1352-302A-88FA-C567D4D69179> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff88055000 -     0x7fff88202f27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff884e6000 -     0x7fff8850dff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff886ab000 -     0x7fff886c6ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8991f000 -     0x7fff89922ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <7C9EC3B7-DDE3-33FF-953F-4067C743951D> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff89b9d000 -     0x7fff89ba2ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff8ae73000 -     0x7fff8ae75ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38>
/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8c6e4000 -     0x7fff8c8c9fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.16) <A63E680E-E4B2-368B-8564-9DBE0D8DDB91> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8c9de000 -     0x7fff8c9e2ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <4E51D5B0-92A0-3D0D-B90E-495A1ED3E391>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8cf49000 -     0x7fff8cf5aff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8d6d3000 -     0x7fff8d702fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8d744000 -     0x7fff8d74bff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff8d74c000 -     0x7fff8d74dff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8d83d000 -     0x7fff8d8c6ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA>
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8d8c7000 -     0x7fff8d8ebfff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8d8ec000 -     0x7fff8d94fffb  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.13.1 - 1.13.1) <2C8E1A73-5AD6-3A7D-8ED8-D6755555A993>
/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration

External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 76
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 206900
    thread_create: 2
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=272.5M
resident=55.7M(20%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=216.8M(80%) Writable
regions: Total=5.6G written=5.4G(96%) resident=4.5G(80%)
swapped_out=938.9M(16%) unallocated=1.1G(20%)   REGION TYPE           
VIRTUAL
===========                      ======= Kernel Alloc Once                     4K MALLOC                              5.6G MALLOC (admin)            
16K MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            1024K        reserved VM
address space (unallocated) STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              10.0M VM_ALLOCATE                  
528K
__DATA                             7600K
__LINKEDIT                         93.2M
__TEXT                            179.4M
__UNICODE                           544K shared memory                         4K
===========                      ======= TOTAL                               6.0G TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      6.0G  

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core
i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel
HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB,
DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446393333334700000000 Memory
Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x857F,
0x483634353155363446393333334700000000 AirPort:
spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom
BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.4f1 13674, 3
services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service:
Ethernet, Ethernet, en0 Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9A302,
320.07 GB Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898 USB Device: Hub USB Device: IR Receiver USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) USB
Device: Hub USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device:
BRCM2070 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller Thunderbolt
Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: Can you possibly minimize the sample? Perhaps replacing the `map`s with a single, looped one, would work. What version of Python?

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks, pandas (iopro?) had no problem with the same file 3 weeks ago. (I had to go back and fix my parsing, but the crash is new.) Just loop over each line, fill in the new variables by looping over the list of each line, and then groupby.sum? The mac Python is `Python 2.7.6 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15) `

Comment: I'm not sure what you just asked (the thing about `groupby.sum`). To clarify, I was saying that since the question is about the *crash* and not the code, there's no reason to have 12 functions if having just one allows the problem to be reproduced. And does the stuff at the end ever get run? If not, remove it. (etc.)

Comment: What happens if you remove the first two filenames from `filelist`? Does it still crash on `oppenvard20012005` or on some other file?

Comment: @unutbu It was a good idea, it proceeded a bit better on a mac (start with the bigger files, so you don't load the temporary memory hog on top of the accumulating memory hog), but still crashes on the fourth file in Windows.

Comment: Perhaps try testing what happens when you remove `iopro` and use `pd.read_table` instead. If it works, you will know the problem has to do with `iopro`. If it still crashes, then we know the problem is with `pandas`, and we have a simpler program to work with.

Comment: @unutbu Good point. But my tables have a lot of extraneous information. And the documentation of the usecols option of `pd.read_table` is sparse…

Comment: [pd.read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html) has parameters like `skiprows`, `nrows`, `iterator`, `usecols`, and others which may help you load just the parts you want.

Comment: @unutbu I tried to do that, but now I cannot map the functions to the result of split in the code above. The error message says that a float is not iterable (presumably the elements of the diagnoses Series?). When I check the elements of diagnoses, it seems to be a Series of lists though…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54388/discussion-between-laszlo-and-unutbu).

Comment: Please start a new question showing a sample of the data, and what you'd like the DataFrame to look like.

Comment: @unutbu I hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23857756/938408