# mapping a (lambda) function to lists of strings fails 'float' object not iterable

Tags: python, list, types, lambda, pandas

I try to understand where my Python script goes awry. I have a pandas Series (`diagnoses`) of lists, each a list of strings (never empty). I can and did verify this with `diagnoses.map(type)` and

```
for x in diagnoses[0]:
    type x
```

Yet when I would map a lambda function to this Series of lists, I get a `TypeError: 'float' object not iterable`.

Imagine the data looking like this:

```
LopNr   AR  var3    va4 var5    var6    var7    var8    var9    var10   DIAGNOS
6   2011                                    S834
6   2011                                    K21 S834
```

And the code is:

```
from pandas import *
tobacco = lambda lst: any( (((x >= 'C30') and (x<'C40')) or ((x >= 'F17') and (x<'F18')))  for x in lst)
treatments = read_table(filename,usecols=[0,1,10])
diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ')
treatments['tobacco'] = diagnoses.map(tobacco)
```

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

PS: The same code definitely runs on a very similar Series if I import the source text file with `IOpro` first and build a dataframe from that adapter, see below. I am not sure why that would change the relevant datatypes, as far as I could verify the pandas Series has lists of strings in either case… This is with Python 2.7.6 and pandas 0.13.1.

```
import iopro
adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename,parser='csv',field_names=True,output='dataframe',delimiter='\t')
treatments = adapter[['LopNr','AR','DIAGNOS']][:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` could happen if the data is missing a value for `DIAGNOS`. For example, when data looks like this:

```
LopNr   AR  var3    va4 var5    var6    var7    var8    var9    var10   DIAGNOS
6   2011    a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   S834
6   2011    a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   
6   2011    a   a   a   a   a   a   a   a   K21 S834
```

Then

```
    In [68]: treatments = pd.read_table('data', usecols=[0,1,10])

In [69]: treatments
Out[69]: 
       LopNr    AR   DIAGNOS
0          6  2011      S834
1          6  2011       NaN
2          6  2011  K21 S834

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

The `NaN` in the `DIAGNOS` column is the source of the problem, since `str.split(' ')` preserves the NaN:

```
In [70]: diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ')

In [71]: diagnoses
Out[72]: 
0         [S834]
1            NaN
2    [K21, S834]
Name: DIAGNOS, dtype: object
```

The `NaN` gets passed to the `tobacco` function when `diganose.map(tobacco)` is called. Since `NaN` is a float and not iterable, the `for x in lst` loop raises the `TypeError`.

---

To avoid this error, replace the NaNs in `treatments['DIAGNOS']`:

```
import pandas as pd

def tobacco(lst):
    return any((('C30' <= x < 'C40') or ('F17' <= x <'F18')) for x in lst)

treatments = pd.read_table('data', usecols=[0,1,10])
treatments['DIAGNOS'].fillna('', inplace=True)
diagnoses = treatments['DIAGNOS'].str.split(' ')
treatments['tobacco'] = diagnoses.map(tobacco)
print(treatments)
```

yields

```
       LopNr    AR   DIAGNOS tobacco
0          6  2011      S834   False
1          6  2011             False
2          6  2011  K21 S834   False

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```